# Prolog: Using A* to solve 8 puzzle

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, path-finding, heuristics, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm trying to implement a solver of an [8-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle). The puzzle board is represented as a list. For example, the goal state:

```
1 | 2 | 3
---------
4 | 5 | 6
---------
7 | 8 | 0
```

is represented as `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]`, where `0` represents the empty space.

I've implemented `move(+Board,-Move)` that succeeds with `Move` as all the possible states of the board one move away from `Board`. In addition I've implemented `solvable(+Board)` that gives `true` or `false` as to whether the board can be solved.

I've also implemented two heuristics, `manhattan(+Board,+Goal,-H)` and `hamming(+Board,+Goal,-H)`, which calculates the heuristics cost from `Board` to `Goal`. For example:

```
?- hamming([1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5],[1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5],H).
H = 0.

?- hamming([1,2,3,4,0,8,7,6,5],[1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5],H).
H = 2.

?- manhattan([1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5],[1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5],H).
H = 0.

?- manhattan([1,2,3,4,0,8,7,6,5],[1,2,3,8,0,4,7,6,5],H).
H = 4.
```

I want to implment `solve(+Board,+Heuristic,-Solution)` that succeeds with `Solution` as one optimal solution to `Board` using the `Heuristic` given, and it must terminate deterministically with precisely one solution. For example:

```
?- solve([0,1,3,4,2,5,7,8,6],manhattan,Solution).
Solution = [
    [0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 6],
    [1, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 7, 8, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0]
].
```

I wrote out the pseudo code for the A* algorithm:

```
For each Child of Board do:
    If Child in Closed do:
        Continue
    If Child not in Closed or G(Board) + 1 < G(Child) do:
        G(Child) := G(Board) + 1
        F(Child) := G(Child) + Heuristic(Child,Goal)
        If Child not in Open do:
            Open := Open + {Child}
```

Where `G(Board)` is the actual cost of `Board`, defined as the length of the optimal path to `Board` from the initial board. `F(Board)` is the combined cost of `Board`, defined as the sum of `G(Board)` and the estimated cost of `Board` (defined by a heuristic function). And of course `Closed` and `Open` are the two sets maintained by the A* algorithm, with `Closed` containing boards that have been visited, `Open` containing boards that have not.

Issue is I have no idea how to do this in Prolog. I suppose that some heap datastructure is necessary to maintain the two list, but have no idea what or how. Any help would be great.